# Dataframe conditional logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe ('dayData') with the columns 'Power1' and 'Power2'

```
      Power1         Power2   
 1.049246442   -0.231991505  
-0.950753558    0.276990531  
-0.950753558    0.531481549  
 0             -0.231991505  
-0.464648091   -0.231991505  
 1.049246442   -1.204952258   
 0.455388896   -0.486482523   
 0.879383766    0.226092327   
-0.50417844     0.83687077   
 0.152025349   -0.359237014
```

I'm trying to use conditional logic to create the 'resultPower' column.  For each row, the logic I'm trying to install is:

```
if (Power1 >= 0 AND Power2 =<0) OR if (Power1 <= 0 AND Power2 >= 0) then 0, return the value for Power1.
```

So when the resultPower column is added the dataframe would look like:

```
      Power1         Power2   ResultPower
 1.049246442   -0.231991505             0
-0.950753558    0.276990531             0
-0.950753558    0.531481549             0
 0             -0.231991505             0
-0.464648091   -0.231991505  -0.464648091
 1.049246442   -1.204952258             0
 0.455388896   -0.486482523             0
 0.879383766    0.226092327   0.879383766
-0.50417844     0.83687077              0
 0.152025349   -0.359237014             0
```

I have used basic conditional logic in pandas before, for example I would be able to check one of the logic conditions i.e.

```
dayData['ResultPower'] = np.where(dayData.Power1 > 0, 0, dayData.Power1)
```

but I can't find how I can add logic conditions with AND / OR functions. To build something like:

```
dayData['ResultPower'] = np.where(dayData.Power1 >= 0 and dayData.Power2 =< 0 or dayData.Power1 =< 0 and dayData.Power2 >= 0, 0, dayData.Power1)
```

Could someone let me know if this is possible and the syntax for doing this please?

#### Dataframe reproduction

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

datastring = StringIO("""\
      Power1         Power2   
 1.049246442   -0.231991505  
-0.950753558    0.276990531  
-0.950753558    0.531481549  
 0             -0.231991505  
-0.464648091   -0.231991505  
 1.049246442   -1.204952258   
 0.455388896   -0.486482523   
 0.879383766    0.226092327   
-0.50417844     0.83687077   
 0.152025349   -0.359237014  
""")

df = pd.read_table(datastring, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Comment: You could convert it into a single condition by checking if the product of power1 and power2 is negative (or zero --- your example is inconsistent with your description for the case where one of them is zero).

Comment: As @BrenBarn suggested: `df['ResultPower'] = np.where(df.Power1 * df.Power2 > 0, df.Power1, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['ResultPower'] = df['Power1']
cond1 = (df.Power1 >= 0) & (df.Power2 <= 0)
cond2 = (df.Power1 <= 0) & (df.Power2 >= 0)
df.loc[cond1 | cond2, 'ResultPower'] = 0
```

Using timeit: 100 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop

Answer (score 0):

When you want element-wise logical operations on pandas objects, you need to use `&` for `and` and `|` for `or`. So, this is what you are looking for:

```
In [15]: dayData
Out[15]: 
     Power1    Power2
0  1.049246 -0.231992
1 -0.950754  0.276991
2 -0.950754  0.531482
3  0.000000 -0.231992
4 -0.464648 -0.231992
5  1.049246 -1.204952
6  0.455389 -0.486483
7  0.879384  0.226092
8 -0.504178  0.836871
9  0.152025 -0.359237

In [16]: dayData['ResultsPower'] = np.where(((dayData.Power1 >= 0) & (dayData.Power2 <= 0)) | ((dayData.Power1 <= 0) & (dayData.Power2 >=0)),0, dayData.Power1)

In [17]: dayData
Out[17]: 
     Power1    Power2  ResultsPower
0  1.049246 -0.231992      0.000000
1 -0.950754  0.276991      0.000000
2 -0.950754  0.531482      0.000000
3  0.000000 -0.231992      0.000000
4 -0.464648 -0.231992     -0.464648
5  1.049246 -1.204952      0.000000
6  0.455389 -0.486483      0.000000
7  0.879384  0.226092      0.879384
8 -0.504178  0.836871      0.000000
9  0.152025 -0.359237      0.000000
```

Read more about it here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/gotchas.html#bitwise-boolean

Another approach is to use the `apply` method of dataframes, which applies a function to a row or columns of the dataframe. First, define your function:

```
In [18]: def my_function(S):
   ....:     if ((S.Power1 >=0) and (S.Power2 <=0)) or ((S.Power1 <=0) and (S.Power2 >= 0)):
   ....:         return 0
   ....:     else:
   ....:         return S.Power1
   ....:
```

Now use the `apply` method with axis=1 if you want to work with each row:

```
In [29]: dayData.apply(my_function, axis=1)
Out[29]: 
0    0.000000
1    0.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.000000
4   -0.464648
5    0.000000
6    0.000000
7    0.879384
8    0.000000
9    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

Now we can compare the speed of each of these operations:

```
In [31]: timeit np.where(((dayData.Power1 >= 0) & (dayData.Power2 <= 0)) | ((dayData.Power1 <= 0) & (dayData.Power2 >=0)),0, dayData.Power1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.21 ms per loop

In [32]: timeit dayData.apply(my_function, axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 990 µs per loop
```

So it seems that in this case using apply is faster, but that may be because it has to convert data-structures.